# RegionIntersection for CountryData polygons

Tags: regions, geography

I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64.

```
r1 = CountryData["France"]["Polygon"];
r2 = CountryData["Germany"]["Polygon"];
RegionQ /@ {r1, r2}
```

> {True, True}

Following statements work:

```
rm = RegionMeasure /@ {r1, r2}
Plus @@ rm
```

This works but ignores the units.

```
RegionMeasure[RegionUnion[r1, r2]]
```

which leads us to the question. The intersection should logically be zero but it fails after thinking about it for some time.

```
RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[r1, r2]]
```

**Question**

Is there a reason why `RegionUnion` works for country polygons but `RegionIntersection` does not? Are there workarounds or better workflows for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Motivation**

The original motivation for this question comes from the need to find intersections between polygons for ancient empires and modern states. For example, the Persian empire spread over many present-day countries.

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"]]
```

[image]

Comment: There are two issues in this case. The first is that these regions consist of `GeoPosition` data, and region functions are not really designed to operate with it. Secondly, coordinates are machine-precision reals, and region functions are known not to always work reasonably with such data, but `Rationalize[..., 0]` on all numeric quantities usually helps. The issue in this case is, though, that after such fixes, the computation still takes ages.

Comment: FYI: GeoArea will give result with units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, `GeoPosition`s and `Region`s don't mix in Mathematica, and if something like what's mentioned in the quesion works, it's a pure coincidence. Using projections etc. one can accomplish some of this stuff without excess effort, though.

This is bit of a hack:

```
Area[RegionIntersection[
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   CountryData["France", {"Polygon", "Mollweide"}]],
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   CountryData["Germany", {"Polygon", "Mollweide"}]]]]

(* 0 *)
```

Here polygons with `GeoPosition`s are projected to equal-area `"Mollweide"` projection (direct discretization of `CountryData` `"Polygon"`s would result 3D surfaces!) and boundary-discretized for efficient intersection processing.

The unit of the area in this case is steradians, but this is a projection-specific property. I believe computing areas from this projection ignores some geoid details, though, and for instance the area of France differs between different polygon-derived methods by about 0.25%.

**EDIT**:

One can also perform this transformation to `Polygon`s with `GeoPosition` coordinates from other sources using `GeoGridPosition`:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"] /. 
  p_GeoPosition :> First@GeoGridPosition[p, "Mollweide"]]
```

[image]

Areas computed through geographic computation and steradians on Mollweide projection differ a little, but probably not too much for most tasks:

```
{Area[Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"]],
 (Entity["Planet", "Earth"][
     EntityProperty["Planet", "SurfaceArea"]]/(4 Pi))
  Area[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"] /. 
     p_GeoPosition :> First@GeoGridPosition[p, "Mollweide"]]]}

(* {Quantity[5.53446*10^6, ("Kilometers")^2], 
 Quantity[5.53553*10^6, ("Kilometers")^2]} *)
```

What's best, using region operators work on resulting `BoundaryMeshRegions`, and one can compute areas of intersections between them.

**EDIT 2**:

Actually you can convert these regions which have been operated under a projection back to geographic computation entities, at least if the geometry is not too complex for `MeshPrimitives` (basically having holes, which is sometimes a real problem). This way one can compute more precise area:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"] /. 
   p_GeoPosition :> First@GeoGridPosition[p, "Mercator"]] //
 Area@Polygon@
    GeoPosition@
     GeoGridPosition[MeshPrimitives[#, 2][[All, 1]], "Mercator"] &

(* Quantity[5.53446*10^6, ("Kilometers")^2] *)
```

Of course the operation above is absurd and is really relevant on intersections and such as an input. With above code, polygon intersections are intended to be performed under Mercator projection (which is conformal), and area computation is performed by proper geo code. I suspect this is a bit better than just using latitude-longitude pairs as 2D polygon coordinates, but probably not by much.

Comment: How do I convert a GeoPosition based polygon to "Mollweide"? As an example, how do I convert `Entity["HistoricalCountry", "PersianEmpire"]["Polygon"]` to "Mollweide"? The original motivation was to find out intersection of historical entities with modern countries. Your answer looks good. Thanks. I am going to also add this shortly to the post under the title `Motivation`.

Comment: @Syed I added an example on usage of `GeoGridPosition` for this.

Comment: @Syed Added even simpler approach for better area computation with a caveat that it doesn't work under all scenarios...